How to config SplitChunkPlugin
I try to split "src/util.js" from "src/index.js", but it doesn't work.
Here is my code: https://github.com/jrr997/webpack-split-chunk
The problem is "src/index.js" isn't loaded. Maybe something wrongs in my webpack config.
I expect that "./src/util.js" should be loaded before "./src/index.js", but nothing is loaded. I can't figure out why after reading the docs and some posts.
